# Should you include time as a continuous predictor when estimating incidence or prevalence?

Tags: regression, time-series, splines, epidemiology, prevalence

Suppose one has a time series of disease counts and populations (at risk, total etc.) or, equivalently, binary events of disease status.
Then suppose one wanted to present estimates of incidence or prevalence over the time series.

One could calculate separate estimates for each year. I believe this would be the same as a regression model with dummy variables for each year. Or is it better to fit time (e.g. year) as a continuous explanatory variable (linear, polynomial, spline etc.)? In the former case, the estimate at each year is not influenced by estimates at other time points. In the latter, I think the estimate at each year would be "adjusted" by the trend. Im thinking that this would provide a better estimate at a given time point, since it's taking other time points into account (more so the closer in time).

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious, but would appreciate some guidance on whether my thoughts make any sense and which approach might be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.  Time is continuous and needs to be analyzed as such.  But also think about decomposing time into long-term smooth nonlinear trends and seasonal variation.  An example is [here](https://hbiostat.org/R/rms/gtrans.html).  A spline is used for the long-term trend and a harmonic series for seasonal effects.

Comment: If the time period defined for calculating incidence or prevalence itself is one (WHOLE) year, would modelling time as a continuous term be contradictory since this would in theory allow model predictions at e.g. 2.5, 3.7 years etc. Prevalence and incidence are only defined here for whole year periods and not decimals / periods between years.

Comment: You can add long-term trends to short-term trends, so getting a prediction for a specific day of a specific year should not be a a problem if the model fits OK.

Comment: If one does not have day or month information they must specify a time within the year to regress on e.g. year mid point, end of year. I think this would be problematic. Also, would this not change the time unit for prevalence or incidence to per day? This is not what is required...rather we need "per year".